# windows 10 keeps turning off file and printer sharing

Tags: windows, file-sharing, private, accessibility

**EDIT:** I'm not sure why this has two downvotes already. Perhaps before doing so, those inclined to downvote can explain why, which would be helpful to me even if you don't have an answer.

I have not been able to find an answer as to why my changing File/Print sharing to on is *immediately* is turned off again in Windows. Perhaps in trying to be brief, people think I neglected all the basic steps to determine why this is happening. I have checked the following:

- All systems have network discovery turned on.
- The two desktops have File and printer sharing turned on, *while I'm unable to do so on the laptop*.
- There are shared folders available on all three machines.
- Those shared folders accept "everyone" and they have read/write access.
- All machines are in Workgroup
- I've looked up the `\\NAME is not accessible` and `System error 67` messages, to no avail.
- **So the *only* difference I can find is that I can't turn File/print sharing on on the laptop; when I do so, it simply reverts!!!**

---

I have a home office setup with a laptop, desktop, plus my wife's desktop. All are using Windows 10 2004. All are on one LAN (Private network), plus of course access to the internet through an Asus router.

I can access files just fine from the laptop, and between the two desktop machines, but if I try to access files sitting on either desktop from the laptop, I get errors!

The laptop can see the two desktops from the view provided by the Network desktop icon. If you try to click one you get the `\\NAME is not accessible. You might not have permissions to use this network resource`.

If I try `net use`, I get
`System error 67 has occurred.`
`The network name cannot be found.`
even though the desktops have directories that can be shared.

On the laptop, if I go to `Network and Sharing Center`, `Change advanced sharing settings`, I find `Turn off file and printer sharing` is enabled. If I click `Turn on file and printer sharing`, hit Save changes, then reenter the same dialog, they are again turned off!

I even have turned off Windows Defender Firewall for Private networks on the laptop!

The laptop is using Windows Defender Antivirus, which is the only other place I can conceive of the problem is arising. I mean, what else could be turning File and printer sharing off every time I enable it?

More importantly, how can I enable this capability? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using AD authentication on your network, or are all the workstations using local accounts?

Comment: They are all using local accounts. Since these are all on a private LAN, I didn't see a need for stronger authentication. And all three are in Workgroup, not Homegroup. I also edited the question to clarify I've been through everything I can think of to isolate other causes of the error.

Comment: Using Active Directory (AD) authentication isn't "stronger authentication", rather it is a method of central network management for user authentication, in the sense that you can domain-join PCs and use the same username and password on any PC joined to that domain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isn't this the thing in Windows when you're connecting to a new WiFi and/or network, it's asking you what type of network it is "public,home,work". If you've picked public it won't connect and won't let anything to connect.

Microsoft [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043043/windows-10-make-network-public-private) how to check the configuration. Hope that's it.

It's little bit weird you can't translate the hostname so `\\name` isn't working, you can try `\\192.168.0.3` or whatever is IP address of one of the connected computers, at least `ping 192.168.0.3` shall work (change the IP address to desired).

If you still have trouble, put side by side computer which works and which is not, on both hit: `Win+R` and run command `services.msc`, compare the services on both computers, is possible one of the services is not running and that's why the sharing can't start.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Using the IP address produces the same error message. Your suggestion about Services may be the key: on the two desktops, the Workstation service is running, but not on the laptop. When trying to start on the laptop, I get "could not start... Error 1075: The dependency service does not exist or has been marked for deletion"! Trying to find all those dependent components now. The one dependent service, Network Store Interface Service, is running, but I need to look for the other "components" - Browser and SMB 2.0 Redirector Wrapper and Engine, having subcomponents...

Comment: Thanks to @Geeky Masters for the pointer to compare services! This problem turned up for me with the update of Windows 10 version 2004, and was not an issue before that. This feature requires "Workstation" service to be running; if you can't start it manually, check to be sure you have "Browser" or "Computer Browser" service installed, and if not, install the SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support windows feature. Once that was installed and I rebooted, Workstation service came up, and the issue was resolved!

Comment: "SMBv1 is not installed by default in Windows 10 version 1709, Windows Server version 1709 and later versions"

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/smbv1-not-installed-by-default-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the privileges for the required documents: folders and files? You can set access to files and folders by selecting the appropriate Windows users (Accounts).

Based on the error, it can be assumed that you do not have enough rights to do this.

Comment: Yes, I've checked privileges.

Comment: also in windows, credintial manager remove all saved passwords related to file share.. i had an issue with saved credentials

Comment: Thanks @Aravinda. There was no credential for the desktop, so I created one on the laptop, BUT the problem is still there: the laptop denies the desktop exists, despite being able to ping it.

Comment: in services.msc (via run), what is the status of Server service ? running well ?